# Access VBA- insert checkbox after text in Word Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

my VBA dynamically writes several tables depending on criteria and works quite well.

For example here is adding a row, formatting it and advancing to the next row.

```
        oDoc.Tables(t).Rows.Add 'add a row below control number
        oDoc.Tables(t).Rows(i).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        oDoc.Tables(t).Rows(i).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = oTableHeaderColor
        i = i + 1 'advance to row below control number row.
        oDoc.Tables(t).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = "Check Definition"
```

I do it in this manner because I just don't know how many rows any given table is - so I create the rows as I need them, might be clumsy but it works.

What I need to do is add a check-able checkbox to rows with text like this.

> Planned: ☐

I've tried several ways that just don't seem to work. as far as I can tell it's because i'm not creating the table then selecting it. I've tried recording a macro and that just shows the bit about selection first.

Here's what I've got, it pops an error.

```
oDoc.Tables(t).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = "Planned: " & oDoc.Tables(t).Cell(i, 1).Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlCheckBox)
```

I get "requested member of the collection doesn't exist.

If I try to put it on two lines it will just overwrite cell 1. with the checkbox and I can't seem to position it to the end of the cell first. Any ideas?  I've tried insertbefore and that works but I have to insert several checkboxes in the same cell.

Any ideas?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting text + checkbox + other text + second checkbox into one cell is tricky.

This may be one of the few cases, where you actually have to use the `Selection` object.

This works for me in Word:

```vb
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = ThisDocument
Const t = 1
Const i = 1

Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim iCheck As Long
Dim sLabel As String

Set rng = oDoc.Tables(t).Cell(i, 2).Range
rng.Select
With Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    For iCheck = 1 To 3
        sLabel = Choose(iCheck, "Planned: ", " Done: ", " Perhaps: ")

        .TypeText Text:=sLabel
        .Range.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlCheckBox
        ' move cursor after checkbox
        .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Next iCheck
End With
```

In Access, use `oWord.Selection` instead (or what you have as reference to Word).

The following works for a single checkbox, but I didn't manage to create a second one *after* additional text.

```vb
Dim rng As Word.Range
Set rng = oDoc.Tables(t).Cell(i, 2).Range
rng.Text = "Planned: "
' set range to end of cell
rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
' I'm not entirely sure why this is needed, but without the checkbox goes into the next cell
rng.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
rng.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
```

Comment: it worked.  I can't believe how close I had come to it before but by darn you nailed it.

All I had to do with your word vba was add the oWord.Selection inplace of Selection and i could add as many boxes as I wanted.

Comment: I ended up using this with a modification. Instead of choose I just used UBound and split it.